# Excel vba and arrayformula

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to get the values from an array formula into VBA as an array.  Simple example:  I have a cell (let's say D1) which has an array formula in it such as
=A1:A10*B1:B10
when I highlight this on the spreadsheet and press F9 I'll get an array of 10 numbers, say, ={5;12;15;24;25;24;42;40;54;70}

I want to be able to store these values in a VBA array:  a(0)=5, a(1)=12, a(3)=15 etc; you get the idea.

Tried hunting for an answer on this one, but can't find anything relevant even on MSFT. Lots of answers about how to go the other way from VBA to the worksheet range (I know that one) but not this way.  Looked at trying to do it via a ParamArray (the number of elements won't be fixed), by assigning directly to a undimensioned array and via EVALUATE(range) but I can't get any of these to work.  I feel I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you have tried already. But `Evaluate` should work.

If I have the following:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub getArrayFormulaResult()

 sFormula = Range("D1").FormulaArray

 aResult = Evaluate(sFormula)

 MsgBox Join(Application.Transpose(aResult), ",")

End Sub
```

will result in:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Dim var as variant
var=Worksheets("MySheet").Evaluate(Worksheets("MySheet").Range("D1").formula)
```

Note you should use Worksheet.Evaluate to ensure this works when Mysheet is not the active sheet. The result will always be a 2_D array (with one column for your example array formula)